# Polite way to ask about something that I previously requested

Tags: politeness

Say I have the sentence below about papers I requested previously. (as I am reminding somebody that I haven't received something)

> 先日{せんじつ}に頼{たの}んだ書類{しょるい}ですが・・・

Is there any way to make a sentence like this more polite (humbling)? Do the below sentences make sense or is there a better way?

> 先日{せんじつ}にお頼{たの}みした書類{しょるい}ですが・・・
>
> 先日{せんじつ}にお願{ねが}いした書類{しょるい}ですが・・・

Answer (score 4):

I would say "先日、お願いした書類ですが".

"お頼みした" sounds funny (to me.)

Comment: I totally agree, nevertheless I happen to know one real-life sample who actually use お頼みする...

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that natives are generally oblique in the beginning. Then, they slowly become more specific. Hopefully, this is all you'd need to say.

> 「この前お願いしたものですが、...」

That obscures the impolite fact of how long you've been waiting. And, (in my experience as a non-native speaker), initially saying exactly what you requested feels abrupt and analogous to physically "pointing". As much as possible, just let them figure out the situation for themselves.